# Deep-Links in One-Page Layout using AJAX is accessing .php-Files directly

Tags: jquery, ajax, single-page-application, history.js

Quick structure overview:

`domain.com` will call the `index.php`. In it's JavaScript file I check for the current `location.pathname`, pass that info via AJAX to a `class/nav.php` which in turn gets and returns the contents from the specific file.

E.g: `domain.com/about` returns the contents of `about.php` which will be inserted into a part from `index.php`.
`domain.com` and `domain.com/` will return contents of `home.php`.

That worked fine in all web-apps I've build so far. But currently I have the following problem:

Accessing the app via `domain.com` will correctly insert contents from `home.php`.
Following a link on the site like `href="/about"` will also correctly return the contents of `about.php`.
But calling `domain.com/about` directly, is displaying the `about.php`file directly (locally) or showing a 404 error (live server). `index.php` is not called, hence the JavaScript is not executed and of course everything breaks apart.

I can't figure out why this is happening.

You can see the problem live here:
`www.einzelstueck-shop.com`

Open the navigation on the top left and click `Ringe` - the page navigates correctly.
Now reload the page or open `www.einzelstueck-shop.com/ringe` manually and you'll see the described behaviour.

Code i used (everytime) for navigating:
(I use history.js and jQuery)

JS:

```
var History = window.History;
History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function () {
    console.log('statechange');
    var State = History.getState();
    navigateTo(null);
});

function navigateTo(target) {

    if(!target) {
        target = removeSlash(window.location.pathname);
    }
    console.log('navigate to: ' + target);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "class/nav.php",
        data: { location: target }
    }).done(function (data) {

        if(data) {
            // insert HTML
        } else {
            console.log('not happening...');
            History.pushState("1", 'Home', '/');
        }

    }).fail(function (data) {
        console.log('FAIL');
        console.log(data);
        return false;
    });
}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$targetLocation = $_POST['location'];

if($targetLocation == '/' || $targetLocation == '' || $targetLocation == 'home') {
    $file = 'home';
    $targetLocation = '';
} else {
    $file = $targetLocation;
}

if(file_exists('../'.$file.'.php')) {
    $data['target'] = $targetLocation;
    $data['html'] = file_get_contents('../'.$file.'.php');
} else {
    $data = null;
}

echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found it. The .htaccess, redirecting all URLs to index.php, was missing which is fixing the problem on the live server. Locally (using vmware and vagrant) the .htaccess was missing one line that needed to be added: `Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews`

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# remove trailing slash from URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^ index.php?request=%{THE_REQUEST} [L]
```